# Character can not move any more

Tags: java, swing, animation, keylistener

So here is the code after taking the tips into account.
The map is kept being repainted, the keylistener has changed but there still seems to be a problem.

The problem again is, the little square in the upper left corner will not move, which is the desired outcome.

```
package schoolgamev2;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Spel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Speelveld map = new Speelveld();
        map.Speelveld();
        map.GenerateMap();
    }
}

class Speelveld extends JPanel {

    final int rijen = 16;
    final int kolommen = 16;
    Speler speler = new Speler();
    Loopgebied loopgebied = new Loopgebied();
    Blokken blok = new Blokken();

    int[][] coordinaten = new int[rijen][kolommen];

    public void Speelveld() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(this);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(new KeyListener(this));

    }

    //genereer map
    public void GenerateMap() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int x;
        int y;
        for (y = 0; y < rijen; y++) {  //scan langs y
            for (x = 0; x < kolommen; x++) { //scan langs x
                //selecteert type blok voor coordinaten x y
                coordinaten[x][y] = random.nextInt(4);
                //debugprint
            }
            //debugprint
        }
        coordinaten[0][0] = 4; //speler begint altijd links boven
        coordinaten[15][15] = 5; //finish is altijd rechts onder
    }

    public int[][] getCoordinaten() {
        return coordinaten;
    }

    public Speler getSpeler2() {
        return speler;
    }

    public int getSpelerX() {
        return speler.getX();
    }

    public int getSpelerY() {
        return speler.getY();
    }

    public void setSpelerX(int x) {
        speler.setX(x);
    }

    public void setSpelerY(int y) {
        speler.setY(y);
    }

    //@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int x;
        int y;
        for (y = 0; y < rijen; y++) {  //scan langs y
            System.out.println("");
            for (x = 0; x < kolommen; x++) { //scan langs x
                blok.setX(x);
                blok.setY(y);
                blok.setType(coordinaten[x][y]);
                System.out.print(coordinaten[x][y] + " ");
                switch (blok.getType()) {

                    case 0:
                        loopgebied.teken(g);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        speler.teken(g);

                    /*case 5:
                        eindveld.teken(g);
                        break;*/
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

        }

    }

}

class Speler extends Blokken {

    Blokken blok = new Blokken();

    public void teken(Graphics g) {

        g.drawRect(blok.getX(), blok.getY(), 10, 10);
    }

}

class Loopgebied extends Blokken {

    Blokken blok = new Blokken();

    public void teken(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(blok.getX() * size, blok.getY() * size, size, size);
    }
}

class Blokken {

    private static int x;
    private static int y;
    private static int type;
    public int size = 16;

    //setters voor x y en type
    public void setX(int xIn) {
        x = xIn;
    }

    public void setY(int yIn) {
        y = yIn;
    }

    public void setType(int typeIn) {
        type = typeIn;

    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

}

class KeyListener extends KeyAdapter {

    private static final int SCALE = 3;
    private Speelveld speelveld;

    public KeyListener(Speelveld speelveld) {
        this.speelveld = speelveld;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        int deltaX = 0;
        int deltaY = 0;
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            deltaX = -1 * SCALE;
            deltaY = 0;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            deltaX = 0;
            deltaY = -1 * SCALE;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            deltaX = 1 * SCALE;
            deltaY = 0;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            deltaX = 0;
            deltaY = 1 * SCALE;
        } else {
            return;
        }

        int x = speelveld.getSpelerX() + deltaX;
        int y = speelveld.getSpelerY() + deltaY;

        speelveld.setSpelerX(x);
        speelveld.setSpelerY(y);
        speelveld.repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: Ugh my formatting is bad, I am so sorry.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") really should include the desired behavior, and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please create and post your [mcve] so we can play with a small compilable and runnable program and so that we can test your code ourselves, and hopefully modify it so that it will work. Note that we **do not want to see your entire program**, nor should you post a link to a code repository. Instead keep it small, keep it simple, and make it functioning. Luck.

Comment: I would help too just explain what is happening when you try to run your creation. Exception? Or not working as expected?

Comment: Again without runnable code I cannot give a precise answer with code, again I request that you strive to improve this question. All I can do is make a general suggestion. I'm guessing that this is in Dutch (Nederlandse taal?) and that Speler is your player class. If so, then you are probably in error having it extend JPanel. Instead you'll likely want to have *one* JPanel that does your drawing, and make your Speler (and most other classes) non-GUI classes, but logical classes that yes, know how to "paint" themselves, but aren't actual components.

Comment: By "know how to paint themselves, I mean that they have a `public void paint(Graphics2D g)` method or `public void verf(Graphics2D g)` in your case that the drawing JPanel calls on them within its paintComponent method.

Comment: For an example of a similar problem that I'm describing above, please see [this question and my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34436045/522444). Note that my answer includes a valid [mcve] -- a small program that is fully runnable and demonstrates the point that I was trying to make.

Comment: I am trying to make the small runnable program, but it still needs four classes to run. Also I am done rewriting the question and will edit it in right now.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you got your player, the Speler class, that extends JPanel and is wired to use a KeyListener, but note that it is not being used as a JPanel, and so the KeyListener is non-functioning, because they only work when they have been added to a *visible* component that has focus.

Suggestions:

- Again as per comments, make Speler a non-GUI *logical* class. Meaning don't have it extend JPanel or any other Swing component, and certainly don't add a KeyListener to it.
- Instead give it code for the player's behavior and for having the player draw itself, and that's it. What I'm suggesting is that you try to separate part of your "Model" here the player from the "View" here the Swing GUI.
- Have one JPanel and only one that does drawing. Have it override paintComponent (don't forget to call the super's paintComponent within it), and have it draw each logical component by calling the logical component's draw method (`public void verf(Graphics2D g2)`? or `public void teken(Graphics2D g2)`?) within its paintComponent method.
- As a general rule, you also don't want your GUI component classes, the JPanel here, directly implementing listener interfaces, such as the KeyListener, but will want to keep them separate.
- Either make this drawing JPanel focusable, give it focus and add the KeyListener, a separate class,  to it.
- Or better, use Key Bindings as per the tutorial: [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

For example the simple [MCVE] below doesn't use a Swing Timer or change velocities, but rather it uses a KeyListener to change position of the Speler2 object using only one drawing JPanel and a KeyListener. If I were making this more robust and larger, I would use the Swing Timer, would use Key Bindings, and would change the velocities using the key bindings.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Spel2 {

    private static final int VELD_WIDTH = 500;

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Speelveld2 speelveld2 = new Speelveld2(VELD_WIDTH, VELD_WIDTH);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Spel2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(speelveld2);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        speelveld2.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter {
    private static final int SCALE = 3;
    private Speelveld2 speelveld2;

    public MyKeyListener(Speelveld2 speelveld2) {
        this.speelveld2 = speelveld2;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        int deltaX = 0;
        int deltaY = 0;
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            deltaX = -1 * SCALE;
            deltaY = 0;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            deltaX = 0;
            deltaY = -1 * SCALE;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            deltaX = 1 * SCALE;
            deltaY = 0;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            deltaX = 0;
            deltaY = 1 * SCALE;
        } else {
            return;
        }

        int x = speelveld2.getSpelerX() + deltaX;
        int y = speelveld2.getSpelerY() + deltaY;

        speelveld2.setSpelerX(x);
        speelveld2.setSpelerY(y);
        speelveld2.repaint();        
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Speelveld2 extends JPanel {
    private int prefW;
    private int prefH;
    private Speler2 speler2 = new Speler2();

    public Speelveld2(int prefW, int prefH) {
        this.prefW = prefW;
        this.prefH = prefH;

        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener(this));
    }

    public Speler2 getSpeler2() {
        return speler2;
    }

    public int getSpelerX() {
        return speler2.getX();
    }

    public int getSpelerY() {
        return speler2.getY();
    }

    public void setSpelerX(int x) {
        speler2.setX(x);
    }

    public void setSpelerY(int y) {
        speler2.setY(y);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        speler2.teken(g2);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
    }

}

class Speler2 extends Blokken2 {
    private static final int RECT_W = 10;

    public Speler2() {
        super(BlokkenType.SPELER);
    }

    @Override
    public void teken(Graphics2D g2) {
        int x = getX();
        int y = getY();
        g2.drawRect(x, y, RECT_W, RECT_W);
    }
}

class Blokken2 {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int velx = 0;
    private int vely = 0;
    private BlokkenType type;
    private BufferedImage img;

    public Blokken2(BlokkenType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getVelx() {
        return velx;
    }

    public void setVelx(int velx) {
        this.velx = velx;
    }

    public int getVely() {
        return vely;
    }

    public void setVely(int vely) {
        this.vely = vely;
    }

    public BlokkenType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(BlokkenType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setImg(BufferedImage img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public BufferedImage getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void teken(Graphics2D g2) {
        if (img != null) {
            g2.drawImage(img, x, y, null);
        }
    }
}

enum BlokkenType {
    LOOPGEBIED, BARRICADE, MUUR, SLEUTEN, SPELER, EINDVELD
}
```

---

Edit: your latest code has an error here:

```
class Speler extends Blokken {

    Blokken blok = new Blokken();

    public void teken(Graphics g) {

        g.drawRect(blok.getX(), blok.getY(), 10, 10);
    }

}
```

---

Regarding your edit:

Now when you create a Speler instance, you create **TWO** Blokken instances, one which **is the** Speler instance since it extends Blokken and the other which is **contained by** the Speler instance since it also has a Blokken field.

You update the x/y state of the first one, but you draw with the second one, and that's why no motion is being displayed. The solution is obvious: use one or the other but not both. Either have Speler extend Blokken or have it contain a Blokken instance but don't do both.

Comment: We have taken your tips into account, but still there seems to be something wrong. I have re-edited my question, you can now copy and paste it at once, and run the code.

Comment: I can't upvote because my rating is too low. I have read the link you have send me, I tried right after reading it. And also I am sorry, I didn't want to repost the question and take up attention for something that is already being worked on.

Comment: @OguzKh: I see your problem... hang on please

Comment: I will rewrite the former question, that is no problem at all. Least I could do after some help.

Comment: @OguzKh: Please see edit. It's a very basic Java problem, one you should probably have worked on debugging a little longer before jumping back here so quickly as I'm pretty sure you'd have solved it with a little more effort.

Comment: Done. The problem lies somewhere else I suppose.
We removed the Blokken instance and changed the painting code to: g.drawRect(super.getX(), super.getY(), 10, 10);

The logic here is getting the method from the super class rather than using a blokken instance and getting the method. We are currently looking into it but to no avail yet.